# li elements are getting double margin, ul element cant be properly sized

Tags: css

This problem is a double whammy, essentially, I have this setup:

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: -5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: tomato;
}

li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

ul:after{
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p299jd55/2/

The problem is that I want the list items to pretend as though the `<ul>` isn't there.  The version I have currently works on the vertical, but not on the horizontal.  Additionally, the `<ul>` is a bit smaller than the divs so the list elements will not line up correctly with the divs even if they would normally.  I want the list elements to appear as the other divs do (except smaller).  The problem is that I need to keep them in the `<ul>` element in order for my VM binding library (KnockoutJS) to work correctly.

Is there any way to get around this without introducing a wrapper for the divs as well?  I'd like to keep down the number of elements that exist solely to hack CSS to a minimum.  If there is no way to do this without wrapping the divs, I am okay with that but I would prefer it be the last resort option.

Comment: I couldn't get you. Can you add a picture how you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

**CSS Changes**

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0; /* Changed */
    padding: 0;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px 0; /* Changed */
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

### [Fiddle illustrating the change](http://jsfiddle.net/p299jd55/4/)

What's going on here is that your margins were all over the place.  No need to set negative margins on the `ul` when you're going to be simply overriding them in the `li`.  That's what was causing your layout to be wonky.

## Update

Based on your feedback in the comments, here's how you can flush the `div` section to your `ul`

**[Fiddle with flush div section](http://jsfiddle.net/p299jd55/6)**

Basically, we're using your clearfix solution to pull the following elements upward by adding this line to `ul:after`:

```
margin-bottom: -10px;
```

and then adding this rule:

```
li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

## Update part deux

**Based on your comments**

That's incredibly simple.

Just add float to both your `li` elements and your `div` elements.  Remove the clearfix section.

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p299jd55/7/)**

Comment: The problem with this is that now the spacing between the `ul` and the `div` elements exists.  I essentially want the `ul` element to be invisible, and for all of the `li` elements to act as though there is no wrapper.  My original edit left this out on accident, but I added it back in later.

Comment: I want a setup like this: http://jsfiddle.net/b0Lsv3m8/1/  Essentially, I want the <ul> element to essentially not exist.  It needs to be there for semantic and for VM binding reasons, but it shouldn't really be there.  I hope that expresses it better.

Comment: Oh wow I'm surprised I didn't think to just remove the clearfix.  Nice simple solution to a problem I way overcomplicated.